# How do I add corner radius and icons to buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How do I make a similar view like the one below

[image]

So technically both will be a button, and Currently I'm using 2 buttons and I use stack view to group it together

[image]

The questions are

1. How do I add corner radius to stack view
2. How do I add icons and the line between them

Comment: put 2 button into a view, constraint them equal height, add a view with height = 1 between them, give a view a corner radius, profit?

Comment: why stack view? you can use UIView or staic tableView too.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Stack view appearance

You can't apply cornerRadius directly to UIStackView. You should embed it inside other UIView which could be configured as you want to.

> The UIStackView is a nonrendering subclass of
> UIView
> ; that is, it does not provide any user interface of its own. Instead, it just manages the position and size of its arranged views. As a result, some properties (like
> backgroundColor
> ) have no effect on the stack view. Similarly, you cannot override
> layerClass
> ,
> draw(*:)
> , or draw(*:in:).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

## 2. Icons and a line

Layout on your screenshot could be reproduces in few ways:

- TableView: use cell.imageView and cell separator;
- Manually built layout *(makes more sense if you have only a few options to choose from)*

In the second case you will have a Vertical StackView containing two views. Each view will have the **imageView** and **titleLabel**, first view will have pre-defined height constraint while the second view height will have **equal** constraint with the first one. To make a separator, create a 1pt height view inside the first view constraint to the bottom.

At this point I still don't understand why you want to use StackView. If you want your options list to be variable in count, use TableView. If some options should be hidden in certain cases, both StackView and TableView will fit, but if it is a Static menu I'd prefer replacing StackView with UIView.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add corner Radius, Border Line, Image in UIButton you can use Our Custom Controls.
you have not add **single line of code you can set from storyboard**.
Just visit this link.
let me know if you have any doubts.

https://github.com/ZetrixWeb-Swift-iOS/ZWButton